# Why does setting view dimensions asynchronously not work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

This works

```
myView.layoutParams = myView.layoutParams.apply { height = 100 }
```

But neither this (with android-ktx)

```
myView.doOnLayout {
    myView.layoutParams = myView.layoutParams.apply { height = 100 }
}
```

nor this

```
myView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        myView.layoutParams = myView.layoutParams.apply { height = 100 }
        myView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
    }
})
```

nor even this

```
postDelayed({
    myView.layoutParams = myView.layoutParams.apply { height = 100 }
}, 100)
```

works. Why?

Comment: what thread are these lambdas executed on?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Same UI thread

Answer (score 6):

Changing height or width of `LayoutParams` doesn't impact its view. `LayoutParams` is simple value holder. To apply changes you have to call `requestLayout`:

```
myView.doOnLayout { 
    myView.layoutParams.height = 100
    myView.requestLayout() 
}
```

Another way is reassignment of `layoutParams`:

```
myView.doOnLayout {
    myView.layoutParams = myView.layoutParams.apply {
        height = 100
    }
}
```

Your first example works probably because assignment is performed even before view is drawn.

Comment: You're right, but I remember doing this is Java without calling `requestLayout()` or `invalidate()` or anything, probably because there would have been other layout passes after setting the height, initiated by other children. At any rate, frustratingly, neither calling `requestLayout()`, `forceLayout()`, `invalidate()`, setting new LayoutParams, or any of these help. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll update the question.